# How can I see incoming Requests in IIS7?

Tags: web-services, iis-7

I have a created web service that takes 2 complex types as parameters.  I can use the auto-generated WSDL to create a new application that calls my web service and it works perfectly.

However, a 3rd party consumer is having trouble calling my web service.  I see their incoming request in the IIS7 log file and a 500 error is being returned to them.

I suspect that their request is malformed.  I would like to be able to see the entire <soap:envelope> that IIS7 is receiving so that I can troubleshoot the issue.  I am using Windows Server 2008 and IIS7.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would open up a copy of [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) while they are putting their request through.  You can then see each packet which comes to your server.  Wireshark is cool because it can put all of the packets back together so you can see the full HTTP request they're sending.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew something like this had to exist but I couldn't find it anywhere.  WireShark worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  It's kind of a learning curve, but it's pretty awesome.  It's the only thing I ever use to really get to the bottom of Kerberos errors as well...